# Why is the menu not showing in this react example?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I took the NavBar example from react bootstrap and tried to run however it wont render.

Any ideas, there are no runtime errors, so I am a bit stumped.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mccarthy-y9tb4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <Header>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </Header>
  );
}
```

You're using the `Header` component inside itself, which create a infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, that blocked me.  I misunderstood what the return function is doing.